# Create OneToMany models in django

Tags: python, django, models, one-to-many

I want to create one to many model in django.
for example I have

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobile = 1  #I want OneToMany
    website = models.URLField()

class Mobile(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(min_length=7, max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(min_length=7, max_length=20)
```

How I can do this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in django that is used for such relationships.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField()


class Mobile(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(min_length = 7, max_length = 20)
    description = models.CharField(min_length = 7, max_length = 20)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

Once you have this, the `UserProfile` object can have multiple mobile numbers which can be accessed through `userprof_obj.mobile_set` which is a `RelationshipManager`. To get all mobile numbers, you can do `userprof_obj.mobile_set.all()`.

Comment: How I get get all mobile number of a person ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't You want to use Many-To-One relationship

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    phone_number = models.CharField(min_length=7, max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(min_length=7, max_length=20)
```